# JavaFX ExtensionFilter on the FileChooser save dialog is too wide on macOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, filechooser

The UI for the extension filter takes up the full width of the window:

[image: screenshot of the FileChooser UI with the extension filter dropdown far too wide]

Compare that to Chrome's save dialog, for example:

[image: screenshot of Chrome's save dialog with the extension filter dropdown the correct width]

---

MCVE: https://github.com/deNowww/MCVE-FileChooserExtensionFilterSaveDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, it is a known issue since 2018 ([see here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209399)).
you may track this issue to see if they are ever gonna fix it or when they decide to fix it.

Comment: Damn, oh well. I guess I can live with a weird looking FileChooser UI for now.